# Python write string to memory an read the memory with other Python program

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi

I receive with my Python program a string with 12 comma separated values over Ethernet.

Now I want to provide the values for other programs but I do not want to write the values in a file.  Writing to a file would occur very often and would thus strain the SD-card of my RaspberryPi.

The other programs must only read and not write the values.

Please can some one tell me if I have a chance to write the complete string or the separated values to a defined space of the memory an read this space with other Python programs?

I use python in the version 2.7.

I hope my English is good enough to explain the problem.  Thank you for the Help.

Comment: A safer way would be to write the values to a file then have another program read the file.

Comment: it's a bit of an XY problem, since you provide a solution already. In case you wanted to share data with other processes, have a look at [multiprocessing.queue](http://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/communication.html)

Comment: You need interprocess communication of any kind.  You could write to a file in a filesystem on a ramdisk, if you want to spare your SD card; in Ubuntu for this you can use `/run/shm/` for this; have a look at the output of `mount | grep tmpfs` on your RP.  Other options like communicating via sockets, pipes, fifos of course also exist.

Comment: Using a sockets to transfer information between processes could be a better solution if performance is not an issue. This solution will even sound better the day you will decide to distribute the computing, or just for debugging from a remote machine. Maybe you really need shared memory, but make sure sockets are not a more appropriate solution before you do.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for information about shared memory.  I haven't used it, personally, but here are some resources I found:

- [Wikipedia: Shared Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory_%28interprocess_communication%29)
- [POSIX IPC for Python - Semaphores, Shared Memory and Message Queues](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/)

Answer (score 2):

@dsh has already provided some info on shared memory, the other (slightly higher level) idea I could recommend is using [python sockets](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html).

They have a great [how-to](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) on implementing sockets and I'd recommend you check out a non-blocking, STREAM socket to communicate between your programs.